# How to convert an associative array of dates into object in jQuery for flatpickr

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flatpickr

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, and not getting anywhere at all.

OK, so I have a database table that saves staff holidays, using a start and an end date, so it's a range. If it's a single day, it will be the same date but normally it's a range.

I am using Flatpickr on my site in order to book a job for a specific date and time, but I need to disable dates that the chosen staff member is NOT available on. When the user selects a staff member, there is an ajax call to the holiday table in the database and fetches any holiday dates, puts them in an array then returns it back to the ajax in JSON. Here's my call (`$(this).val()` refers to the staff dropdown, and this will run on change):

```
var staffId = $(this).val();
var dateObj = {};
var parsed;

$.post( '/get-availability', { staff_id: staffId }
).done( function(response) {
    if(response.length > 0) {
        parsed = JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(parsed, function(i, element) {
            console.log("i : " + i);
            dateObj = { from : element['from'], to : element['to'] };
        });

    }
```

The PHP in get-availability is as follows:

```
$staff_id = $request->get('staff_id');
$staff_entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Staff')->findOneBy(array('id' => $staff_id));
// get all holidays for the staff member
$holiday_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Holiday');
$holidays = $holiday_repo->findBy(array('staff' => $staff_entity));
$result = array();
if(!empty($holidays)) {
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($holidays as $row) {
        $result[$x]['from'] = $row->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d');
        $result[$x]['to'] = $row->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d');
        $x ++;
    }
}

return new Response(json_encode($result));
```

Coming back to the ajax, I need to layout my flatpickr config as follows (the dates are just examples):

```
disable: [
    {
        from: "2017-04-01",
        to: "2017-06-01"
    },
    {
        from: "2017-09-01",
        to: "2017-12-01"
    }
]
```

But my dateObj will get overwritten each time, so it only adds the LAST date range in:

```
var config = {
    disable: [
        dateObj
    ]
};
```

Basically, I need to know how to correctly adapt the $.each loop in order to get a result like the first example above, but nothing works. So far I've tried:

```
dateObj += { from : element['from'], to : element['to'] };
dateObj.i = { from : element['from'], to : element['to'] };
```

Then making it an array and trying:

```
dateObj[i] = { from : element['from'], to : element['to'] };
JSON.stringify(dateObj)
```

But every single one fails. I'm hoping someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

OK, in the end I used the DatePeriod() function and passed all the dates back as a single array, rather than in the `from` and `to` blocks. Not exactly the most optimised version of doing it but it works.

```
foreach ($holidays as $row) {
    $start_date = new \DateTime($row->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d'));
    $end_date = new \DateTime($row->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d'));
    $date_range = new \DatePeriod($start_date, new \DateInterval('P1D'), $end_date);
    foreach($date_range as $date){
        $date_array[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    // Add the end date as this is not included in the date period.
    $date_array[] = $row->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

`$date_array` then gets encoded and passed back to the Ajax where it is parsed and added to the config of flatpickr.